# Understanding tools:overrideLibrary on Android

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have the main app with `minSdk="14"`, and the Facebook SDK for Android v. 4.16.1 has `minSdk="15"`

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.dmitriev_m.sample_android"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.16.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.dmitriev_m.sample_android">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="25"
        tools:overrideLibrary="com.facebook, android.support.customtabs" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is what the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html#override_wzxhzdk38uses-sdk_for_imported_libraries) says about merging `AndroidManifest.xml` files:

> By default, when importing a library with a minSdkVersion value that's
>   higher than the main manifest file, an error occurs and the library
>   cannot be imported. To make the merger tool ignore this conflict and
>   import the library while keeping your app's lower minSdkVersion value,
>   add the overrideLibrary attribute to the  tag. The attribute
>   value can be one or more library package names (comma-separated),
>   indicating **the libraries that can override the main manifest's
>   minSdkVersion**.

But my merged manifest looks like the app overrode manifest file of the Facebook SDK (the min SDK is 14):

[image: Merged Manifest, min SDK = 14]

Is it safe to run this application? I mean when the Facebook SDK calls a method from Android API 15, the app should crash, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YEs, if the library call an API 15 function and the device is only API 14, it will crash.  If the device is API15 or higher it will still work.

I wouldn't worry about it in this case though.  14 was Anroid 3.x.  There were only a tiny number of 3.x devices made-  Android tablets didn't take off until after 4.0 was released.  The percentage of 3.x models in use is less than .1% of all devices.  If they don't work, is it really worth the time and effort to support them?  Honestly I'd just raise your minsdk to 15 or higher.  (raising it to 19 only eliminates 10% of the worldwide market, which would heavily skew to low income countries in Asia, Africa, and South America.  If your major targets are the US and EU, it may not be worth the cost of supporting that).

Comment: 14 is not Android 3.x. It's Android 4.0 https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels

Comment: You're right.  But its still less than .1% of all devices   https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html